# What is the inverse of find() function in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

In Matlab I can find all non zero entries in a vector like this:

```
>> v = [0 1 0 0 1]

v =

     0     1     0     0     1

>> indices = find(v)

indices =

     2     5
```

Assuming that my vector `v` can only have `0` and `1` values, what is a simple way to reproduce `v` from the `indices` vector?

Comment: How do you know the size of `v` from `indices`? In your example, `v = [0 1 0 0 1 0]` is also a solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to know what the shape `v` is (i.e. how long `v` is if it's a vector as in your example), but once you know that it's trivial:

```
n = 5;
v_reconstructed = zeros(1, n);
v_reconstructed(indices) = 1;
```

if you don't know how long `v` is then you won't capture any `0`s after the last `1` in `v`...

BTW if you are working with sparse matrices then you might want this actually:

```
v = sparse([0 1 0 0 1]);
v_reconstructed = full(v);
```

Comment: In second line, `v_reconstructed(n) = 0;` may be faster

Comment: Better: `v_reconstructed = zeros(size(v)); v_reconstructed(indices) = 1;`

Comment: @Dan Then how would you know that n=5?

Comment: @SamRoberts I'm assuming you know how long `v` is going to be, maybe it's the same length as another vector you have or `n` is just known, but that `v` itself for some reason doesn't exist :/ basically I think knowledge of `n` is a less stringent assumption than knowledge of `v`.

Comment: @Dan OK, I guess that's true. Well, the suggestion is there anyway, just in case you do have `v` available.

Comment: @Sam If you have v, the solution is `v_reconstructed = v;` :-)

Comment: Thanks this will work great! I'm using it for sparse binary matrices, converting between dense and sparse representations.  (so yes, the length is known)

Comment: @LuisMendo <facepalm> OK, I'm going to leave quietly now and hope no-one notices my idiocy...

Comment: @SamRoberts Hey, that kind of stuff happens to me all the time ;-)

Comment: @portforwardpodcast if you're working with spare matrices then you should be using `sparse` and [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) surely?

Answer (score 6):

i used to use sparse and full but now i switched to accumarray, because it has simpler format.

in your example:

```
   v=accumarray([2;5],1)'
```

additionally, you can also cycle values (i think), according to the first matlab example:

```
Create a 5-by-1 vector, summing values for repeated 1-D subscripts:
   subs = [1; 2; 4; 2; 4];
   A = accumarray(subs, 101:105)
```

of course, according to its name, this function is built to do fancier things.

Comment: This answer is better because it works for N-D matrix indexes as well.  2-D example: accumarray([1,3;2,4],1) == [0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1].  This might not include rows or columns but with logical indexing it just will assume zeros/false there anyways.